# Assigning contents to a variable with include/require_once

Tags: php, html, variables, output-buffering

Is it possible to do like

```
$var = require_once('lol.php');
```

so that any HTML output that `lol.php` does will go inside `$var`?

I know about output buffering, but is there some special built-in function that already does this?

Comment: If you *think* you need to do this, you should probably just fix the included file. Modules (as opposed to plain, stupid templates) that grab `stdout` and treat it as theirs are broken.

Comment: You can make `lol.php` contents return an array or object.

Comment: unfortunately i have no control over lol.php...

Comment: So what you want is a web crawler? Or just pass the contents of the file into a string?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`$var = require_once('lol.php');` will only put the return value of the file into `$var`. If you don't return anything from it, it'll just be `null`.

If you want the output you will need to use output buffering:

```
ob_start();
require_once('lol.php');
$var = ob_get_clean();
```

Answer (score 7):

The assignment from an `=include()` call will only get you a possible `return` value from that script, not any output.

To make this possible you would have to modify the include script to capture the output:

```
 <?php
      ob_start();

      ...

      return ob_get_clean();
 ?>
```